# Richtext field (CKEditor) doesnt keep value after 2nd submit for new(unsaved) document

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I have a serious problems with richtext field in my app. (Domino R901). I have extracted the scenario into simple Xpage with just one field and submit button only.

I have simple XPage now, with one field and submit button. RT field looks like this:

```
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1" value="#{docui.body}"></xp:inputRichText>
```

Plus there is a standard button which runs JAVA action below with full submit:

This action is called on button click:

```
public void r(DominoDocument docui)  throws NotesException {
 Document cdoc = docui.getDocument(true);

 if (cdoc.hasItem("body")){
    print("Body exist");  
 } else {
    print("Body doesnt exist");
 }

 docui.setDocument(cdoc);

}
```

Now when I enter some text into rich text field (CKEditor) and click on submit, it reloads the page  (full submit) and I can see the text in CKEditor properly. Now when I do it 2nd time, text disapear and even in my JAVA code it says, that 'Body doesnt exist'. The problem seems to lie in fact, that CKEditor doesnt send content to server, when there is no change to it ... see here [richtext control doesn't store the input content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588879/richtext-control-doesnt-store-the-input-content) . I understand this behaviour for saved existing document, but when you have a new document, it simply doesnt submit value during second submit because it doesnt changed between requests. But because its a new unsaved document the value is simply discarded / lost . Is there any workaround how to deal with this?

Comment: Do you add a datasource to the document, could it be that after the full  submit and reload the database don't create a new doc and lost also the reference to the old document.

Comment: The problem is, that in real code there are some manual validation checks and when not all fields are valid, the document is not saved and is send back to browser with some message. Then because CKEditor check if content chnaged, and content doesnt changed so its not beeing sent back to the server ... its a case for new document ...

Comment: What is the point of this code line: docui.setDocument(cdoc)? I will suggest that you work on the NotesXspDocument ony (docui).

Comment: Well the real code is much longer and computes something I need to get back to browser. NotesXspDocument  document doesnt contain all Document methods ... docui.setDocument(cdoc); works nice except of CKEditor for new documents ...

Comment: Real problem is related to the fact, that CKEditor sends its content back to server only when it changed. So if you enter some text, its sent to server, but when you doesnt save the content to DB on the next request its not sent back to server, if you didnt update the CKEditor content.

Comment: David, did you find a workaround?

Comment: No, I tried to hack CEditor isDirty JS function so the content would be always dirty and send back to browser what would be fine but it doesnt work for me, Domino simply ignores the value ... Domino generates some fieldId_h a fieldId_mod fields for each CKEditor in generated HTML but I could not find any docs on this ...